# Get single Object Express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to get a single data object from this express.js model

```
 models.courses.findOne({
     where: {id: req.params.course_id},
     attributes: ['coursename']
   })
   .then(function(courses) {
    console.log(courses.coursename);
   });
```

It is printing the name of the course, however I want to get that course.coursename on a separate variable outside of the model.

Is that possible?

thanks

Comment: var courseName = courses.coursename ? not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I want to use courses.coursename out side of "models.courses.findOne()

Comment: so declare a var courseName  = "" outside of  models.courses.findOne declaration. Then, assign it it's value inside , where you're console.log is